# How to change name of a file or even a array in a static name parameter?

Tags: c++, c, file, iteration

I have:

```
sscanf(string1, "%d", &aux);
sscanf(string2, "%d", &aux);
sscanf(string3, "%d", &aux);
sscanf(string4, "%d", &aux);
```

And I want something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
sscanf(string<i>, "%d", &aux);
```

There's a way to do that?

P.S.: I gave a string example but I want to do it for everything that has a static name, like a file.

Comment: Why not use a 2-d array ?

Comment: I can't use 2d files, for example.

Comment: File pointer you want to say .

Comment: That helped me. Not what I wanted but I think I can make that work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The language is not designed how the way you are thinking. But you can solve your problem by using arrays.